# Adding returning form_invalid (or something) with custom form errors in custom signup form with django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to prohibit duplicate signups from a single ip. Here is my code.

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    def signup(self, request, user):
        ip = get_client_ip(request)
        if UserProfile.objects.filter(registration_ip=ip).exists():
            self.add_error(
                None, "You cannot register more than one account from the same IP")
        else:
            user.userprofile.registration_ip = ip
            user.userprofile.save()
            user.save()
```

Currently, when a user registers having the same ip as another registered user, the form still validates. I need the form to return an error. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

(The above code is an override of the SignupForm of the django-allauth package)

The if statement works fine. At first I tried using `raise ValidationError` and that worked fine, but that is not good for UX. I need the form to invalidate and return my custom error on the form page.

Comment: What does `self.add_error` do here?

Comment: nothing, that's why I posted the question

Comment: From where does signup fun is called?

Comment: Try `count = UserProfile.objects.filter(registration_ip=ip).count() if count > 0:` see if that works.

Comment: How you will handle this in UI? How does your view function looks like?

Comment: @AtleyVarghese I don't understand your question. I am using the django-allauth package, as mentioned in the title.

Comment: @Ahtisham in this approach I would just `user_ip = UserProfile.objects.filter(registration_ip=ip) and then if user_ip: return {'result': False, 'error': 'Duplicate user from the same IP is prohibited'}` and then I would use js to show this error for user.

Comment: @Ahtisham there is no problem with the if statement. my problem is with the form not being invalidated.

Comment: @simkus https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L205 again, this is using the django-allauth package, as stated in the title

Comment: what form? show us the form code, or this is it??

Comment: this is the form code. The form overrides the SignupForm of the django-allauth package

Comment: ahh, sorry, ok then.

Comment: That is not the correct way of overriding `django-allauth` `SignupForm` This is how you do it `from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):` see doc https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html

Comment: so `class SignupForm(forms.Form):` is the django default form not `django-allauth`

Comment: ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.SignupForm' in settings.py. Works generally fine when I use `raise ValidationError` (though the error page is not good for UX). I am asking this question because I need to return custom errors on the form page for the user.

Comment: Well you can create a method in your views and move your `signup` method in there .

Answer (score 0):

That filtering, returns an istance and it does not check the IP if they are same or not just checks if exist.
First you need to make uniqe `registration_ip` via Model.
Then you can use `clean` method via forms like:

```
def clean_registration_ip(self,request):
     registration_ip = self.cleaned_data['registration_ip']
     if UserProfile.objects.filter(registration_ip=registration_ip).exists():
          raise forms.ValidationError("This IP exist")
     return registration_ip
```

Comment: My problem is not with the if statement. That works fine. The intended goal is to check if a registration_ip exists. My problem is with the form not invalidating. I need the form to invalidate with my custom error.

Comment: So you can use forms.ValidationError()

Comment: I used that, it returns an error page, not good for UX. I want the form errors to display on the form page, as usual when a form invalidates.

Comment: No Mike it does not return error page. You can use in your template under the input tag  as `{{form.registration_ip.errors }}`. And raise message appears there.

Comment: If you are using with your style it can be..I am talking about best practice of validate a form. I am using forms as well. I have 5-6 forms and all validations in `forms.py` . According to field_name or whole validations I am handling via forms and make form throwing raise error if invalid. If form is invalid you need to redirect the page to html where form is placed. You dont redirect anything and waiting something magical ????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Use the clean function:

```
def clean_registration_ip(self):
    registration_ip = self.cleaned_data.get('registration_ip')
    if : # your logic
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your msg")
    return registration_ip
```